# How to implement a plugin, that modifies the original module only when required?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a plugin extending an original module.
It should only modify the module, when explicitly required.

Problem:
As soon as it is required once, the original module is modified forever, also for cases where the plugin is not a dependency.
The order doesn't matter here, it's enough to require the plugin once.

Example:

```
define("main", [], function() {
    return {opt: "A"};
});
define("plugin", ["main"], function(obj) {
    obj.opt = "B";
});
require(["main", "plugin"], function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.opt); // should log B
});
require(["main"], function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.opt); // should log A but logs B
});
```

I guess the way to go is to somehow tell require to always reload `main` from source instead of using the cached version.
I have no idea how, though.
Or maybe there's an even more elegant way?

Please enlighten me, guys.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r75e446f

**UPDATE:** Some might find it important to know that I need this for my karma unit test environment to test a module with and without the plugin.

**UPDATE2:** Look below for my own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out how to achieve, what I want and thought I'd share it here.

The answer is called 'context', which is an option in the requirejs config.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion

Here's how I implemented my solution:

```
var reqOne = require.config({
    context: 'one'
});
var reqTwo = require.config({
    context: 'two'
});
reqOne(["main", "plugin"], function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.opt); // logs B
});
reqTwo(["main"], function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.opt); // logs A
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzakh4y9/), because the second require will try to load the main module externally and I can't upload files to jsfiddle.

But the mere fact, that he tries to do that and doesn't use the 'main' module already loaded in the other require, should be proof that his method works.
If the definitions are outsourced to single files this works like a charm.

Thanks for everybody who chimed in.

Comment: As soon as your app becomes substantial, this causes problems. Each context is **totally** isolated from the others. If all contexts use the same 3rd party libs (which must be the case if you load the same app in different contexts), then they all have to load these libs. If they use jQuery, they will load jQuery multiple times. jQuery may or may not detect that it is already loaded ( depends on whether you use ``noConflict``). RequireJS still has to fetch the lib and execute it multiple times, which is far from optimal. If you design your application correctly, you can avoid all this.

Comment: Louis, technically, you are correct and as discussed multiple times here I am aware of that. This however is exactly the answer to my question in this case, because I didn't ask "how to make this more elegant or properly" but "how to do this".
The reason (which I added later)  is that my application is a testing environment. So here it doesn't matter at all that libs are loaded multiple times. It's actually desired.
Endusers won't care about the plugin being constantly loaded, if required once. It's actually more convenient for them.
So again: This is exactly what I've ben looking for.

Comment: In your comment  you assert "I didn't ask "how to make this more elegant or properly"". However, this is straight from your question: "Or maybe there's an even more elegant way?"

Comment: heheh touché.
I did not mean this in an architectural sense though, but in relation to what was written before. I meant wether there may be a more elegant way to achieve what I want other than undefining the module. I can see how my choice of words may not have been precise enough and I apologize.

Answer (score 4):

RequireJS modules are singletons. If you load `main` once, twice, 10 times, you are always going to get the same module. And so if you modify its state, it is modified for all modules that use it. It is possible to tell RequireJS to undefine the module but I do not recommend it as it will just make your code obscure.

If I wanted to do what you are trying to do I'd design my code something like this:

```
<script>
  define("main", [], function() {
      function Main (opt) {
          this.opt = opt;
      }
      return Main;
  });
  define("plugin1", [], function() {
      return {
          install: function (main) {
              main.opt += " plugin1";
          }
      };
  });
  define("plugin2", [], function() {
      return {
          install: function (main) {
              main.opt += " plugin2";
          }
      };
  });
  // Case 1: no plugins
  require(["main"], function(Main) {
      var main = new Main("A");
      console.log(main.opt);
  });
  // Case 2: only plugin1
  require(["plugin1", "main"], function (plugin1, Main) {
      var main = new Main("A");
      plugin1.install(main);
      console.log(main.opt);
  });
  // Case 3: only plugin2
  require(["plugin2", "main"], function (plugin2, Main) {
      var main = new Main("A");
      plugin2.install(main);
      console.log(main.opt);
  });
  // Case 4: plugin1 and plugin2
  require(["plugin1", "plugin2", "main"], function (plugin1, plugin2,
                                                    Main) {
      var main = new Main("A");
      plugin1.install(main);
      plugin2.install(main);
      console.log(main.opt);
  });
```

Basically, make what is common to all cases a `Main` class which can be initialized at construction *and* which can be modified by plugins. Then each plugin can install itself on `Main`. The code above is a minimal illustration of how it *could* be done. In a real project, the final solution would have to be designed to take into account the specific needs of the project.

Comment: I still think what I need is some form of reinitialization of a module from the defined source. You mentioned undefining it, but this isn't really it, I think.

Comment: From a require stand point I do agree that this is the most correct solution. It actually also came up in a discussion with a colleague. The thing is though, that users are not used to manually initialize plugins. They want to include them and then to work. They usually also don't care about it modifying the module globally, i know. But as I said in my other comment (http://goo.gl/gzew0e) my usecase is tests. So I should make a workaround, not the user. I didn't mention this earlier for brevity reasons.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the original module to be modified for all modules which use it, then your plugin should not modify the original module. Instead, have the plugin return a modified copy of the original module instead.

```
define("main", [], function() {
  return {opt: "A"};
});
define("plugin", ["main"], function(obj) {
  var decorator = {}
  for (var key in obj) { decorator[key] = obj[key];}
  decorator.opt = "B";
  return decorator
});
require(["main", "plugin"], function(obj, plugin) {
  console.log(plugin.opt); // should log B
});
require(["main"], function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.opt); // should log A but logs B
});
```

This will work without any complications if your original object is a simple struct-like object without any functions. If there are functions, or if your original object was constructed using the Module Pattern, then there is a strong possibility of subtle errors in the copy, depending on how the methods were defined.

EDIT 2015-01-13: The OP clarified his question that he would like a way for his tests to be able to run both modified and unmodified original module without having to reload the page. In that case, I would recommend using [require.undef](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef) to unload the main module and then reload it without having to reload the entire page.

Comment: I see how that is the more correct way, but users are not used to referring to the plugin as the constructor, but the main module.
Let me explain: In general I don't think it will be a problem, that the plugin modifies the module forever. It's the same when using jQuery after all and thus expected behavior.
My usecase however is unit tests. In karma I want to be able to test the module with and without the plugin loaded. So far I have not found a way to do that other than reloading the whole page.

Comment: @JanPaepke, please clarify your original question with the testing concern, as that's a big change to the question context. I've modified my answer to account for it.

Comment: Well I don't think it's that much of a gamechanger. I didn't ask how to make it better or more "correct" in terms of a require module, but how to only have a plugin modify a module when it's required, which is exactly what I need, regardless of the context.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to bring up my understanding for discussion.. when we AMD, we define the `module`. Unless the module (in this case is `main`, the defined source) is able to accepting the `plugin` and allow the plugin to change the properties, i guess we're not able to hijack it or it will be an anti-pattern?

what about we extend/clone the defined source, like

```
define("plugin", ["main"], function(obj) {
    return $.extend(true, {}, obj, {opt: "B"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r75e446f/6/

here the `plugin` module is always using the `main` module as its dependency, then when using the module we just directly use the `plugin` module and no longer need to require the `main` module? (by the way i understand this defeat the definition of 'plugin', but my direction is that we're dealing with the `module` as what the requireJs designed to be)

*--2nd approach--*

if you do really want to do it the plugin way, how about the `loader plugin`? like the `text` plugin we always using `require('text!abc.json'). So write a loader and register it to the requireJs's config, and then we could use it. [(more)](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/LoaderPlugins.md#wiki-load)

Answer (score -2):

A more elegant solution would be to take an object-oriented approach, where:

1. the modules return constructors rather than instances, and
2. `plugin` can then be a subclass of `main`.

This is the implementation ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjswensen/yrsgwxws/)):

```
console.clear();
define("Main", [], function() {
    return function() { this.opt = "A"; };
});
define("Plugin", ["Main"], function(Main) {
    return function() {
        Main.call(this);
        this.opt = "B";
    };
});
require(["Plugin"], function(Plugin) {
    console.log((new Plugin()).opt); // should log B
});
require(["Main"], function(Main) {
    console.log((new Main()).opt); // should log A
});
```